# How to convert inline join query result in EntityFramework to an entity

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I have two entities named Customer and Address (one to one mapping, each Customer has an address), and I am using code first approach using Entity Framework.

I have written inline sql query to fetch some details.

```
 var customers= context.Database.SqlQuery<Customer>( 
                   "SELECT * FROM Customer c INNER JOIN Address a ON a.CustomerId = c.Id").ToList();
```

This statement is fetching only Customer details, Address property is NULL for all the customer objects being returned.

How do I get the result of an inline join query as a Customer entity(maintaining the same structure).

Comment: Any reason why you are writing SQL instead of using LINQ queries?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Well, this is not my actual problem. I have just used two sample tables only for demonstration purpose of my question. There is a complex query comprising of joins, filters and conditions.

Comment: all of which can be easier to specify via LINQ

Comment: @YacoubMassad the query includes a full text search as well, that's the main reason I opted for inline query instead of LINQ.

Comment: `SqlQuery` just doesn't create object graphs. Period. But may you can find some inspiration in http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of running the query on the database, running the query on Customer entities solved my problem.

```
 var customers= context.Customer.SqlQuery<Customer>( 
               "SELECT * FROM Customer c INNER JOIN Address a ON a.CustomerId = c.Id").ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to rewrite the SqlQuery using linq and use the Include property:

```
var customers = (from c in context.Customer
  select c).Include(c => c.Address).ToList();
```

See [Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) from MSDN for details.